# How to extract string after 2nd delimiter in R

Tags: r

I have my vector as

```
dt <- c("1:7984985:A:G", "1:7984985-7984985:A:G", "1:7984985-7984985:T:G")
```

I would like to extract everything after 2nd `:`.

The result I would like is
`A:G , A:G, T:G`

What would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match two instances of one or more characters that are not a `:` (`[^:]+`) followed by `:` from the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^([^:]+:){2}", "", dt)
#[1] "A:G" "A:G" "T:G"
```

---

It can be also done with `trimws` (if it is not based on position)

```
trimws(dt, whitespace = "[-0-9:]")
#[1] "A:G" "A:G" "T:G"
```

---

Or using `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(dt, "^([^:]+:){2}")
#[1] "A:G" "A:G" "T:G"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`, capture the items you want to retain in a capturing group `(...)` and refer back to them in the replacement argument to `sub`:

```
sub("^.:[^:]+:(.:.)", "\\1", dt, perl = T)
[1] "A:G" "A:G" "T:G"
```

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract` and positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(dt, "(?<=:)[A-Z]:[A-Z]")
[1] "A:G" "A:G" "T:G"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use str_split which returns a list of 2 values.
´str_split("1:7984985:A:G", "\:",n=3)[[1]][3]´