# Extract everything before second delimiter in R

Tags: r, substring, stringr, gsub

Building off this previous post:
[How to extract string after 2nd delimiter in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764083/how-to-extract-string-after-2nd-delimiter-in-r)

Have a string like the following:

```
"dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv"
```

And want to extract all the values ***before*** the second `/` like:

```
"dat1/set1/"
```

I was using variations of:

```
sub("^([^/]+/){2}", "", "dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv")
```

With `^` and `.*` moved around in different places, but just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use `dirname("dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv")` to get the path to the last directory, if that's what the problem really is. (And `paste0` a `"/"` on the end if needed.)

Comment: I used my own built-in neural network to solve this problem, but I wonder whether ChatGPT would answer this correctly ...

Comment: It's deeper than that unfortunately. It's a list of strings but I didn't clarify that in the thread due to all the extra things that would involve writing.

Comment: @BenBolker No Copilot here unfortunately.

Comment: That occurred to me, but it would be good to give a deeper file path as an example, just to head off inappropriate answers like `dirname()` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```r
sub("(^([^/]+/){2}).*$", "\\1", "dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv")
```

- add `()` around the stuff that defines the stuff up to the second delimiter;
- add `.*$` to include the rest of the line;
- replace the blank-string replacement with a replacement by the first capture group.

@GregorThomas points out that *for this example* `dirname()` would work, but not if your tree is deeper.

Alternatively:

```r
stringr::str_extract("dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv", "^([^/]+/){2}")
```

It seemed as though you could also do this with a lookbehind expression (i.e., define a pattern `"(?<=^([^/]+/){2}).*$"` that says "`.*$` preceded by two delimiters, but don't count delimiter stuff in the matched expression") and replacing with a blank, **but** we run into trouble:

- repetition quantifiers (i.e. "{2}") aren't allowed in lookbehind expressions
- if we spell out the repetition explicitly (`"(?<=^[^/]+/[^/]+/).*$"`) and specify `perl = TRUE` then it notes we're only allowed to use fixed-length expressions
- lookahead/lookbehind always hurts my brain anyway

Comment: That did it. Waiting for the accept button to proc.

Comment: Mine as well. And there's not much there to begin with......

Comment: Okay so follow-up question. I've noticed if the string is something like:
"/dat1/set1/set1_covars.csv" (with the "/" in front),
This no longer works.
Why is that and how would one adjust for such a change?

Comment: I think you would need "(^/?([^/]+/){2}).*$"

Comment: Looks that way.
Thank you so much!